# Perform custom Ajax on Views

Tags: 7, views, ajax

My problem is quite complex here:

I have a view table with pager. However, I don't want the "items per page" to be a select list. I want it to look like links: 5 | 10 | 15 | all. My solution for now is edit the views template and add the links with `href=?items_per_page=5"`and it works fine. But I really don't like that I have to reload the page everytime the link is clicked.

That's why I was thinking if it's possible to bind an onclick event to these links that will change the value of the `<select>` and then send an ajax post submit to the views form. I tried to do some simple `$('form').submit()` but didn't get the expected result (can't remember what I got, but I think either no changes or got redirected to somewhere else). I could not figure out how to mimic an ajax sumbit that views perform on this form.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can utilize [theme_pager](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!pager.inc/function/theme_pager/7) to accomplish your goals.  Look for examples on how `theme_pager` is implemented.  But `theme_pager` is definitely what you want.

Comment: but all I see is the pager to jump to a specific page not the "items per page". Could you leave some more hints?

Answer (score 0):

Set Use Ajax Property to Yes :

[image]

Comment: You misunderstood my question. I know that. I have everything work out fine except for the pager that I want

Comment: Oh okk okk then use Better Expose Filter.

Comment: Looked at it already. It's not available for pager. Also it only has radio buttons and checkboxes